# HAL_I2C_Slave_Receive_IT issue?

Tags: c, stm32, i2c, interrupt-handling

I had a problem using this API HAL_I2C_Slave_Receive_IT(&hi2c1, buff, 100) in case I send 20 bytes for example which is a corrupted frame for me (I am waiting for 100 bytes) then i2c driver will stack this 20 bytes and it does not free them in a manner that the next 100 bytes transmitted will be mixed with that 20 bytes and I will got a corrupted frame in my callback (20 + (100-20))!

Is there a way to avoid this use case other then updating the third parameter in HAL_I2C_Slave_Receive_IT API to 1 instead of 100?

thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to enable either the start, stop, or address matched interrupt, and abort the receive if you get one of these interrupts when less than the full amount of data has been transferred.  Which interrupts are available depend on which STM32 part you are using.

Comment: @TomV thanks for your reply, or could we use I2C_WaitOnRXNEFlagUntilTimeout API to abort reception if a tiemeout occured while RXNE flag is reset ?

Answer (score 0):

This function does not know what your intentions are. You told it to receive 100bytes and it will do it until 100 bytes are actually received or an error occurs. You can send it in one chunk or in many. It will not discard any data.

You need to implement this logic yourself.

Comment: thanks for your reply, so in order to force discarding data there is 2 ways to do that either adding timeout to driver or to produce an error (i don't know how) or is there any other efficient method ?